# How to convert label content to int

Tags: c#, wpf, int, label

Is there a way for me to convert the `lblGVMAmount.Content` (label) to `int`?

```
int amount;
if (int.TryParse(lblGVMAmount.Content, out amount) >= 8000)
    lblUnderRunBumper.Content = "Under-Run Bumper";
```

Error:

> No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments

I've also tried `Convert.ToInt32(lblGVMAmount.Content)`, but it does not work.

**Edit:** After reading this question a year later...I was a newbie back then :P. I've learned a lot and still do.

Comment: How did you manage to compile this code? Int32.TryParse requires at least two parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should take a look at the documentation for [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) but, in anycase you should write

```
int GVMAmount;
if (int.TryParse(lblGVMAmount.Content.ToString(), out GVMAmount))
    if(GVMAmount > 8000) 
        lblUnderRunBumper.Content = "Under-Run Bumper";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man :). I still get this error though: _The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string, out int)' has some invalid arguments_.

Comment: Yes, casting it to string fixed the problem. Thank you!